# interface, how to define default value

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I'm trying to use interfaces in my models and create a default value for it.

```
export interface IPerson {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

class Person implements IPerson {
   id = '';
   name = 'John';
}

export class Family {
 constructor(public address: string,
             public members: Person[] = [new Person()]) {
 }
```

So, what I want to get is a family, and when the person has not name, it will be John by default.

It creates a person with name = null

how can I do it?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, if I write `new Family("")` the new object will have a members member taht will contain a single person with the name `"John"`. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is a tool to define **types of values**, not the **values themselves**.
You can't define the value as an interface.

What you can do, is to set a default value of a `Person` class:

```
class Person implements IPerson {
   constructor(private id='', private name= 'John') {
   }
}
```

So, whenever you are invoking the constructor with `new Person()` it will create an instance with the default values.

Answer (score 1):

Type Script follows the `OOPS` concept. So whatever a `OOPS` `language` does, you can do pretty much the same. As long as `inheritance` and `variable` `initialization` is concern, I don't see any issue in your implementation. It should work as expected.

You can see the working copy here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbb7ij

> Note
>   Your class `Family` has the 2 `parameters`. The `first` one is `address` which is `required` field since you did not provide any `default` value. Second `parameter` is `Users array` and it is `optional` since `default` value is with Array of 1 entry of new User.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty unfamiliar with typescript angularJS syntax, but shouldn't you be creating an array of the Person class instead of the IPerson interface like this:

```
export class Family {
 constructor(public address: string,
         public members: Person[] = [new Person()]) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to implement interface if class has the same name

```
    export interface Person {
      id?: string;
      name?: string;
    }

    export class Person {
      constructor(person?: Person) {
        return {
          id: person ? person.id : '',
          name: person ? person.name : 'John',
        }
      }
    }

    const person = new Person(); // id = '', name = 'John'
    const person2 = new Person({name: 'Morpheus'}); // id = '', name = 'Morpheus'
```