# how to set default property values from an interface in typescript angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, typescript-generics

Using generics is there any way to initialize object with default property values from an interface in typescript angular

I have an interface with properties of different data types in it.

```
Interface ISample {
Id: number
Due: date
Name: string
Address: Array<string
}
```

Need a pure generic logic without help of external packages

Expected object

```
{
id:0
Due: new Date()
Name: null
Address: []
}
```

Comment: you can set default value like this { Id: number Due: date Name: string | 'Aravind ' Address: Array<string>  }

Comment: or you can see more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52858782/interface-how-to-define-default-value

Comment: I am importing those interfaces can't modify.  Any Generic interface logic in TS, to fetch keys and types from interface and assign default values to an object ?

Comment: have seen above link or not ?

Comment: The code here is not a [mcve]; please consider editing it to actually demonstrate what you are trying to do with no typographical or syntax errors. [Generics](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) are a particular feature of TypeScript; are you really talking about generics or do you mean something more like "generally"? With just `tsc`, you cannot reify `interface`s at runtime; the type system is [erased](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure). That means the answer here might be "no" unless you allow external packages or other refactoring.